# Why can't I center my image even when I set img as block element?

Tags: html, css

I have spent a long time trying to figure out why I can't center my img element. I have set it as block element, and set the margin set to auto. However the display is always shown with margin-left  less than margin right.

If anyone can help would be great appreciated.

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul {
  float: right;
}

#logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 92px;
}

#logo p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.5em;
  left: 51em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

  </div>


  <div id="search"></div>
  <div id="button1"></div>
  <div id="buttton2"></div>
</div>


<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/qgxhdg24/

Comment: Not sure why it's looking okay for those guys, but I can confirm it's not centered in that JSFiddle by @JayGould

Comment: As a word of advice always use reset.css(if you aren't already using) so that you get better control over styling.

Comment: CSS reset would not help here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You float the header div but never clear it. Add:

```
#content {
  clear:both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qgxhdg24/1/)**

Comment: Fair enough, I guess you didn't need to remove the height value. It made it go correct after I did, but maybe because of the order I Was doing things. I'll remove my answer, as yours fixes the question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is because of the ul in the header, after the header close tag you should add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul {
  float: right;
}

#logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 92px;
}

#logo p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.5em;
  left: 51em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

  </div>


  <div id="search"></div>
  <div id="button1"></div>
  <div id="buttton2"></div>
</div>


<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination